# WMM and IGRF model?

Tags: magnetic-fields

I am studying about World Magnetic Model (WMM) and International Geomagnetic Reference Field (IGRF) model provides the seven parameters about the earth magnetic field. These models have to be deployed on the nano satellite now i am confused how these models works.

I got one formula for the potential of the field and after taking partial derivative of that formula getting the field strength in the respective direction.

But is there any way to get the satellite attitude by that model and having magnetometer reading. Please give any idea if have.